# I need a Java solver Library work as optimization with the Excel Solver tool

Tags: java, excel, optimization, solver

I just started using Java for building models doing some analysis on PV modules.
I am currently writing a class for a PV module, single diode model. I need to use a few points of data such as 'f(current)=voltage' to be able to find all the factors in the equation.
Excel does have this function, called 'optimization with the Excel Solver tool'.
Is there any good library highly recommended for this function? I have tried 'Choco solver' however it does not support many mathematics function for the constraint. e.g it does not allow you to use a/b, when a or b is a double.

I would be really grateful if anyone could give me a hand on this.

Comment: A couple are mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619860/constrained-optimization-for-nonlinear-multivariable-function-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Try free JSR-331"Java Constraint Programming API" http://openrules.com/jsr331. You may also want to check out http://openrules.com/rulesolver.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use the one from Solver (but its not free)
http://www.solver.com/solver-tools-for-developers.htm

Comment: Thank you Charles, i am a student, and really dont want to pay unless I have to. Is there any free ones i could use?

Comment: They do have a student option ... http://www.solver.com/professor-and-student-users.htm  - or use the free one that comes with Excel (but you would have to program in VBA ratherv than Java)